# Bearing: what's more accurate between compass and GPS

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm planning to write an application for WP7 that help to find the bearing to a certain GPS location previously saved. So I need to know the current bearing in order to draw a line pointing to the start location, but I can have this information in two way: one with the Compass, and if the user is moving by calculating an agle from the GPS coordinate offset. Whicj one is more accurate? Does it make sense to swich from Compass to calculated bearing when the user move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could make sense is if the user is facing say south but travelling north, such as on a bus or train.

Comment: I did not think about the scenario you describe, but in this case wouldn't be necessary to use the Compass always ?

Comment: Depends on what your trying to present, but the compass bearing would be more accurate and faster as GPS relies on receiving and decoding a radio signal consuming more battery. The compass is a single chip that consumes very little in comparison.

Comment: I would like to present an arrow bearing to the original location, so I need the GPS coords anyway

Comment: Then again, it depends on your application, if it is based on the direction they are facing, then use the compass, if its the direction they are travelling in, then use the GPS... or you could do a hybrid so that if they are travelling then use the GPS, when stationary use the compass, depends on your application.